# Function arguments arent the same as the passed parameter

Tags: c++

I am experiencing this weird bug where the variables which are being passed into a function are modified after entering the new stackframe.
I wrote a small file which behaves the same as the main code.

```cpp
cv::Vec3b vec = {0, 0, 0};
std::vector<cv::Vec3b> v(16, vec);
std::vector<poly::pixel *> *pixels = new std::vector<poly::pixel *>();

int i = 0;
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
{
    pixels->push_back(new poly::pixel(*it, i % 4, i / 4));
    i++;
}

poly::orient_pixels(pixels, 4, 4);
```

The offending function is `poly::orient_pixels()` which has a prototype that looks like this:

```cpp
void orient_pixels(std::vector<pixel*>* pixels, const int& width, const int& height);
```

In GDB the parameters look like this before and after the call:
[image: Parameters in GDB]

When looking at the parameters inside the function you can see that there is more than just the vector that is messed up. `width` and `height` which are both constant references somehow get wildly different values than the ones passed into it. The `poly::pixel` class is a self defined class which is supposed to represent a pixel in an image that is read by OpenCV. Does anyone have a suggestion as to what is happening and how to fix it?

My initial thought was that since OpenCV instantiated multiple threads this may be a cause of some sort of stack corruption. As a result I simplified it a lot and made the example above. Seeing as the error is still happening and that there are no other threads being instantiated this does not seem likely.

Comment: In the shown code there is no indication of why there should be corrupted values. If the values are really incorrect (and it is not a problem of where the gdb stepped to, e.g. if you try debug an application with optimizations turned on) It could be that your application is already in an undefined state due to undefined behavior that happened earlier.

Comment: A note: doing `new std::vector<…>()` is in nearly every case wrong. If `orient_pixels` does not claim ownership of `pixels` and uses `pixels` only for the time it is called, you can just write `std::vector<poly::pixel *> pixels{}` and `poly::orient_pixels(&pixels, 4, 4)`. If it claims ownership then and you wrote `orient_pixels` yourself, then you should utilize move semantics. Whether `std::vector<poly::pixel>` would be better than `std::vector<poly::pixel *>` is hard to tell, but in most cases, it would be.

Comment: Isn't it weird that the function expects the width and height parameters to be a reference to int and you are sending the values as right hand values? Maybe try to send a variable that holds the ints

Comment: @DanielNudelman it is a `const int&` so it does not matter. But having `const int&` does not make to much sense, a simple `int` would be sufficient in that case.

Comment: Really no good reason to pass ints as const refs anyway. If you wrote that function, change it to pass them by value.

Comment: Where is the documentation for `orient_pixels`? I can't find it at docs.opencv.org.

Comment: It is by no means a function written by opencv but the implementation of it is not important to the bug

Comment: If you don't know why you see a bug involving `orient_pixels`, then you can't rule out a problem with its implementation, especially if undefined behavior is involved.

Comment: I can rule it out because as you can see in the image above from GDB I am simply stepping into the function and the bug happens... No code executes other than the code associated with the function call itself

Comment: If the shown corruption is due to undefined behavior (which is likely if you can rule out that your application built without any optimizations turned on), and the shown code is the only code in `main` then the error is caused either by some code executed by one of the included or by `poly::pixel`. If there is more code executed before the shown code, then the error might already have happened there. Without a [mcve] it is not possible to tell.

Comment: The code that is shown is the only thing that executes as the constructor for `poly::pixel` uses an initializer list and does nothing more.

Comment: If this is the only code in your `main` function, and `poly::pixel` has no errors. Then there are basically only four options: **1.** your compiler or gdb is broken, which is unlikely **2.** you debug an optimized build **3.** you didn't step into the function and see uninitialized values of the parameters **4.** opencv is linked against a different and incompatible version of the std as your application (could happen on windows). So are you sure that the shown code is the only code that is executed right after the application started? That you have `int main() {` right before the shown code?